# Fast way to align row heights in 2 different tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

Currently using this javascript function to align all the rows by matching their heights in 2 different tables.  Each table has more than 1000 rows.  And this function takes greater than 4 seconds to execute.  Is there a faster way to match two different tables' row heights?  Thanks

```
function alignTableRowHeights() {
    $('#table1 tr').each(function(i) {
        var rowDisplay=$(this).css("display")
        if(rowDisplay!="none"){
            // Row is visible
            var tableTwoRow = $('#table2 tr').get(i);
            var height = $(tableTwoRow).height();        
            $(this).height(height);
        }
    });
}
```

The rows in a table are not all the same height.  Therefore there needs to be logic to get the height of each row individually.  And some rows may be hidden (for expand and collapse) and therefore need to check for whether row is displayed or not.  The purpose is to display the two tables side by side so the visible rows need to stay in sync and aligned.

Comment: You may want to look into a JavaScript solution that only renders the rows that are visible on the screen, so you're not wasting time altering the positioning of rows that are hidden. The first library that comes to mind is https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Comment: Why do you need the script for? Can't you just set the same class for the table and adjust the tr{height:20px;} to both?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript only will be the fastest, however, the slowest part is probably not jQuery itself, but how you're using it:

1. For each row you are querying for all the other rows just to use one. Solution: fetch your query results before the loop for that table
2. For each row you are asking to extract the display attribute from the computed styles. Solution: use jQuery's `:visible` selector so you don't have to perform a separate check.
3. Sometimes manipulation of the DOM while the table is visible can be really slow depending on your layout, styles, etc. Solution: remove the table you are updating from the dom, update the heights, then put it back.

Here's how I might do this:

```
function alignTableRowHeights() {

    // copy the heights into an array
    var heights = [];
    $('#table2').find('tr:visible').each(function(i) {
        heights[i] = $(this).height();
    });

    // get visible table one rows before we remove it from the dom
    var tableOneRows = $('#table1').find('tr:visible');

    // remove table one from the dom
    var tempDiv = $('<div />');
    var table1 = $('#table1');
    table1.replaceWith(tempDiv);

    $.each(tableOneRows, function(i) {
        $(this).height(heights[i]);
    });

    // put table one back in the dom
    tempDiv.replaceWith(table1);

}
```

Comment: thanks.  your implementation did improve the performance.  For the tables with 1000 row each, performance is acceptable in Chrome, but it is still slow in IE 8.

Comment: Unfortunately that is often a side effect of using IE8. I struggle to get reasonable performance in IE8 for many of my projects when they include complex UIs. if you want to experiment some, you could try keeping the table in the dom as well. Obviously if you could merge your two tables in to one you would get the best performance since you wouldn't need JS to make the row height match, but i'm guessing that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the table until the heights are fixed:

```
function alignTableRowHeights () {
    $('#table1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#table1 tr').each(function (i) {
        var rowDisplay = $(this).css("display")
        if (rowDisplay != "none") {
            // Row is visible
            var tableTwoRow = $('#table2 tr').get(i);
            var height = $(tableTwoRow).height();
            $(this).height(height);
        }
    });
    $('#table1').css('display', '');
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Zzg/).